# Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce - Track Product View with 'event' rather than 'pageview'

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

Is this acceptable? Calling the pageview in the header, and then sending an event(s) further down the page?

```
//head
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y');
ga('require', 'ec');
ga('send', 'pageview');  

//inside product details/body
ga('ec:addProduct', {
  'id': 'P12345',
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt',
  'category': 'Apparel',
  'brand': 'Google',
  'variant': 'black'
});

ga('ec:setAction', 'detail');
ga('send', 'event')
```

Would this be better practice?

```
//head
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y');
ga('require', 'ec');

//inside product details/body
ga('ec:addProduct', {
  'id': 'P12345',
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt',
  'category': 'Apparel',
  'brand': 'Google',
  'variant': 'black'
});

ga('ec:setAction', 'detail');


//somewhere near footer
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of the syntax for the event push, when you send an event to GA, you have to include the category and action (as specified here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events). So you would have in your event push:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'eventCategory', 'eventAction');
```

Your eCommerce transaction looks fine.

Not sure about the strategy of sending an event with your pageview though. Usually an event is associated with some action (like a button or link click).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That makes sense. So would it be beneficial to rearrange my code as follows (above)? Moving the ga('send', 'pageview') to the bottom of the page after all other processing completes?

Comment: I think the pageview can be moved to where you had it before (in the head). If you want to track the event where the user clicks on a specific item, like the Warhol t-shirt, then you can perhaps do that from the product listing page (ie. the page where you show all the shirts) and not on the product page for the specific item. Does that make sense?

Comment: That does make sense, but I'm not currently trying to track user interactions (clicks, etc). I just want to know when the product page is viewed. So rather than using ga('send', 'event') - I just move my ga('send', 'pageview'); to the bottom of the page below everything else?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your suggested ga('send', 'pageview') at the bottom is the correct way.

Since you "know" when you render the page that the visitor will see the product detail page you might as well send it with the page view.

Use an event to send enhanced ecommerce tracking that hasn't happened when the page renders, like if the visitor adds the product to their cart. Use a non-interaction event to make it not affect bounce rate (and as suggested above, you should specify a category and an action for your event).